# Sensu Monitoring - how to output on an OK

Tags: sensu

By default, `Sensu` does not output on a status of 0 or OK.

Does anyone know how to change this to allow for output on an OK?

http://sensuapp.org/docs/0.16/checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your check as a metric check and the output will be preserved.

https://sensuapp.org/docs/0.16/checks#metrics-checks

> As the Sensu check specification allows for structured data to be
>   outputted to STDOUT, Sensu can be used as a metric collection agent.
>   To allow check results with a exit status of 0 to produce an event,
>   add "type": "metric" to the check definition.